# new missing/unsatisfied dependencies for jboss 6.4.12

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I am deploying locally using gradle.

Getting new missing/unsatisfied dependency on my jndi lookup name:

> JBAS014775: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.min.comp-alert-manager.EmailAlertHandler.env."${min.email.jndi.lookup.binding}" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.min.comp-alert-manager.EmailAlertHandler.env."com.comp.alert.EmailAlertHandler".session]

where min.email.jndi.lookup.binding is used in EmailAlertHandler.java:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "${min.email.jndi.lookup.binding}")
    private Session session;
```

local.build.properties:

```
min.email.jndi.lookup.binding=java:/jboss/mail/Default
jboss.profile=default
jboss.server.groups=other-server-group
jboss.servers=localhost/server-three
```

mail subsystem in domain.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.2">
      <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
      </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

outbound-socket-binding in domain.xml:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
      <remote-destination host="smtp.comp.com" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

my jboss console is also displaying the correct jndi name

I believe the issue is with my local JBoss EAP 6.4.12 though. A coworker is able to deploy locally without this error. Could be something in my host.xml or domain.xml. What I notice for my coworker is that the server group has a full-ha profile instead of the default for his jboss6. So I did try changing mine to that and adding the full-ha profile xml block to my domain.xml but that did not work.

[image: jboss host screenshot]

[image: jboss profile screenshot]

[image: jboss server group screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my `domain.xml`, the `annotation-property-replacement` tag that each `profile` contains (I was using the `default` jboss profile) needed to be changed from `false` to `true` since my `Session` object is being mapped to `min.email.jndi.lookup.binding` via the `Resource` annotation.

`<annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>`